# Two differentials for one integral? (in polar coordinates)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

In my old Calculus 3 notes, I see that I have written the following:

$$ \int_0^{2 \pi \it}\int_0^1 e^{-r^2} r dr d \theta = 2 \pi \int_0^1 e^{-r^2} r dr d \theta$$

I am puzzled because I believe there should be only one differential per integral.  In particular, the second integral should not have a $d \theta$ at the end of it (since this $d \theta$ belongs to the first integral from 0 to 2).

Can anyone confirm which way is correct?

I am especially puzzled since I seem to repeat this same error a second time in my notes.

Comment: I think you know more about calculus than when you took your notes.  Congratulations!

Comment: (A) Either the first Integral limit is till $2\pi$ (not $2$) Or the second Integral multiplier should be $2$ (not $2\pi$) (B) Other than that , you are correct that the second Integral should not have multiple infinitesimals.

Comment: @Prem Thank you for catching my typo!  The upper limit on the first integral was supposed to be 2$\pi$.  I have fixed this now.

Comment: (C) In the Double Integral , If the Inner Integral had been a function of 2 variables (& 2 infinitesimals $du$ & $dv$) like $u^v+v^u$ then , with Definite Integration , we will still have a function of 1 variable (Area under the Curve) & we will still have 1 infinitesimal left over in the Outer Definite Integration. (D) In Current Double Integral Case , the Inner Integral is a function of 1 variable , hence , with Definite Integration , we get a Constant (Area under the Curve) , where we will still have 1 infinitesimal left over. Hence the Outer Definite Integration involves a linear term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that the person, in the time far far ago, needed a corrector of records and all things important.

It would seem that the correction team took good care of the $ r \, dr \, d\theta$ and would not let $d\theta$ be independent of its friend $r \, dr$ once used.

Otherwise
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \, \int_{0}^{a} e^{- r^2} \, r \, dr \, d\theta &= \int_{0}^{2 \pi} d\theta \, \int_{0}^{a} r \, e^{-r^2} \, dr  \\
&= 2 \pi \, \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right) \, \int_{0}^{a} \frac{d}{dr} \, \left( e^{- r^2} \right) \, dr \\
&= - \pi \left[ e^{-r^2} \right]_{0}^{a} = \pi \, \left(1 - e^{-a^2}\right).
\end{align}

Comment: I just want to make sure I am understanding...  You are saying that there should not be a $d \theta$ on the second integral-- because it has already been "used," correct?

Comment: @math4   Yes, the understanding is correct. It appears, as given in the description, there are some " note taking typos " but the understanding of  what to do and why is known. Here, an attempt to repeat the integrals in in the problem with a few more demonstration steps was given for viewing.

Comment: Thank you!  I understand now.